# Uber Zap Logger: how to prepend every log entry with a string

Tags: go, systemd, systemd-journald, go-zap

I am using my app as a SystemD service and need to prepend every message with an entry level `<LEVEL>` for JournalD like:

```
<6> this is info
<7> this is debug
<4> this is warning
```

Otherwise, JournalD treats all the entries the same level and I want to use its advanced capabilities for displaying logs only of certain level.

How can I prepend every log entry with the correct level label (like for Info it would be `<6>`) with uber-zap library?

EDIT: This is the relevant part of my logger configuration:

```golang
    var config zap.Config

    if production {
        config = zap.NewProductionConfig()
        config.Encoding = `console`
        config.EncoderConfig.TimeKey = "" // no time as SystemD adds timestamp
    } else {
        config = zap.NewDevelopmentConfig()
    }

    config.DisableStacktrace = true
    config.EncoderConfig.EncodeLevel = zapcore.CapitalColorLevelEncoder // colors
    config.OutputPaths = []string{"stdout"}
```

Comment: Is your log output in JSON (standard production logger encoding)?

Comment: No, I am using `console` output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a custom encoder that embeds a `zapcore.Encoder`.

Embedding the encoder gives you the implementation of all methods "for free" with the same configuration you have now. Then you can implement only `EncodeEntry` with the additional logic you require.

**NOTE:** You still have to implement `Clone()` if you plan to use structured logging, e.g. `logger.With()`. More info: [Why custom encoding is lost after calling logger.With in Uber Zap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70502026)

Back to your main question, this is a working example; see the comments in code for additional explanation:

```
type prependEncoder struct {
    // embed a zapcore encoder
    // this makes prependEncoder implement the interface without extra work
    zapcore.Encoder

    // zap buffer pool
    pool buffer.Pool
}

// implementing only EncodeEntry
func (e *prependEncoder) EncodeEntry(entry zapcore.Entry, fields []zapcore.Field) (*buffer.Buffer, error) {
    // new log buffer
    buf := e.pool.Get()

    // prepend the JournalD prefix based on the entry level
    buf.AppendString(e.toJournaldPrefix(entry.Level))
    buf.AppendString(" ")

    // calling the embedded encoder's EncodeEntry to keep the original encoding format 
    consolebuf, err := e.Encoder.EncodeEntry(entry, fields)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    // just write the output into your own buffer
    _, err = buf.Write(consolebuf.Bytes())
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return buf, nil
}

// some mapper function
func (e *prependEncoder) toJournaldPrefix(lvl zapcore.Level) string {
    switch lvl {
    case zapcore.DebugLevel:
        return "<7>"
    case zapcore.InfoLevel:
        return "<6>"
    case zapcore.WarnLevel:
        return "<4>"
    }
    return ""
}
```

Later you construct a logger with a custom core that uses the custom encoder. You initialize the embedded field with the same encoder you are using now. The options you see below mimic the options you currently have.

```
package main

import (
    "go.uber.org/zap"
    "go.uber.org/zap/buffer"
    "go.uber.org/zap/zapcore"
    "os"
)

func getConfig() zap.Config {
    // your current config options
    return config
}

func main() {
    cfg := getConfig()

    // constructing our prependEncoder with a ConsoleEncoder using your original configs
    enc := &prependEncoder{
        Encoder: zapcore.NewConsoleEncoder(cfg.EncoderConfig),
        pool:    buffer.NewPool(),
    }

    logger := zap.New(
        zapcore.NewCore(
            enc,
            os.Stdout,
            zapcore.DebugLevel,
        ),
        // this mimics the behavior of NewProductionConfig.Build
        zap.ErrorOutput(os.Stderr), 
    )

    logger.Info("this is info")
    logger.Debug("this is debug")
    logger.Warn("this is warn")
}
```

Test run output (INFO is printed in blue, DEBUG in pink and WARN in yellow as per your `zapcore.CapitalColorLevelEncoder`):

```
<6> INFO        this is info
<7> DEBUG       this is debug
<4> WARN        this is warn
```

Comment: Thanks, @blackgreen! For some reason, the custom prepending does not work when I add any fields to the logger like `logger.With(zap.String("foo", "bar").Info("whatever")`  - I created a separate question for that (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70502026/why-encoding-is-lost-on-logger-with-call)

Comment: Yes sorry, I limited this answer to the issue at hand, however I probably should've included it here. However the gotcha with `logger.With` is broad enough that it's worth its own Q&A. Answered.