# Why custom encoding is lost after calling logger.With in Uber Zap?

Tags: go, logging, go-zap

(based on this question: [Uber Zap Logger: how to prepend every log entry with a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70489167/uber-zap-logger-how-to-prepend-every-log-entry-with-a-string))

I replaced the Encoder of my uber-zap logger with a custom one to prepend every log entry with a SystemD-friendly error level (`<LEVEL>`), but now after I use the logger with additional fields (`With(fields ...Field)`), the custom prepending is gone:

```golang
package main

import (
    "os"

    "go.uber.org/zap"
    "go.uber.org/zap/buffer"
    "go.uber.org/zap/zapcore"
)

func getConfig() zap.Config {
    // your current config options
    return zap.NewProductionConfig()
}

type prependEncoder struct {
    // embed a zapcore encoder
    // this makes prependEncoder implement the interface without extra work
    zapcore.Encoder

    // zap buffer pool
    pool buffer.Pool
}

// EncodeEntry implementing only EncodeEntry
func (e *prependEncoder) EncodeEntry(entry zapcore.Entry, fields []zapcore.Field) (*buffer.Buffer, error) {
    // new log buffer
    buf := e.pool.Get()

    // prepend the JournalD prefix based on the entry level
    buf.AppendString(e.toJournaldPrefix(entry.Level))
    buf.AppendString(" ")

    // calling the embedded encoder's EncodeEntry to keep the original encoding format
    consolebuf, err := e.Encoder.EncodeEntry(entry, fields)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    // just write the output into your own buffer
    _, err = buf.Write(consolebuf.Bytes())
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return buf, nil
}

// some mapper function
func (e *prependEncoder) toJournaldPrefix(lvl zapcore.Level) string {
    switch lvl {
    case zapcore.DebugLevel:
        return "<7>"
    case zapcore.InfoLevel:
        return "<6>"
    case zapcore.WarnLevel:
        return "<4>"
    }
    return ""
}

func main() {
    cfg := getConfig()

    // constructing our prependEncoder with a ConsoleEncoder using your original configs
    enc := &prependEncoder{
        Encoder: zapcore.NewConsoleEncoder(cfg.EncoderConfig),
        pool:    buffer.NewPool(),
    }

    logger := zap.New(
        zapcore.NewCore(
            enc,
            os.Stdout,
            zapcore.DebugLevel,
        ),
        // this mimics the behavior of NewProductionConfig.Build
        zap.ErrorOutput(os.Stderr),
    )

    logger.Info("this is info")
    logger.Debug("this is debug")
    logger.Warn("this is warn")

    logger = logger.With(zap.String("foo", "bar"))

    logger.With(zap.String("foo", "bar")).Info("this does not have the prefix :(")
}
```

The output I get is:

```
<6> 1.640656130756576e+09   info    this is info
<7> 1.640656130756611e+09   debug   this is debug
<4> 1.640656130756615e+09   warn    this is warn
1.6406561307566311e+09  info    this does not have the prefix :(    {"foo": "bar"}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to also implement `Clone()` from the `zapcore.Encoder` interface. If you wish to keep the parent logger unaltered, you have to construct an actual clone — possibly with the same config, so you might want to store it as a field:

```
type prependEncoder struct {
    zapcore.Encoder
    pool buffer.Pool
    cfg  zapcore.EncoderConfig
}

func (e *prependEncoder) Clone() zapcore.Encoder {
    return &prependEncoder{
        // cloning the encoder with the base config
        Encoder: zapcore.NewConsoleEncoder(e.cfg),
        pool:    buffer.NewPool(),
        cfg:     e.cfg,
    }
}
```

If you don't implement it, the method that runs is the next shallowest one when calling `logger.Clone()`, which is the `Clone()` declared on the embedded `zapcore.Encoder`. That one then doesn't have your custom `EncodeEntry` anymore.

Now running the following:

```
    logger.Info("this is info")
    logger.Debug("this is debug")
    logger.Warn("this is warn")
    child := logger.With(zap.String("foo", "bar"))
    logger.Warn("original")
    child.Info("new one")
```

Outputs:

```sh
<6> INFO        this is info
<7> DEBUG       this is debug
<4> WARN        this is warn
cloning...
<4> WARN        original
<6> INFO        new one {"foo": "bar"}
```